# How to constrain a copy constructor in C#?

Tags: c#

For a simple example, I have this copy constructor in C#:

```
            public Vector2D(Vector2D v)
            {
                m_x = v.m_x;
                m_y = v.m_y;
            }
```

Because I want to constrain the argument to not be modified by mistake, I tried adding 'const' after '('.

For example, I would like something like this:

```
            public Vector2D(const Vector2D v)
            {
                // v.m_x++;  Can't do this mistake anymore
                m_x = v.m_x;
                m_y = v.m_y;
            }
```

However, I noticed in C# it does not allow this. If you can imagine methods being very large as I have seen in C++, this makes sense to have this constraint option.

What is the alternative?

Comment: To have a not mutable Vector2D class to start with.

Comment: Not an answer to your question but double checking your code would solve the problem.

Comment: Can't you turn Vector2D into a struct?

Comment: I did eventually change it to a struct. That doesn't solve the constraint issue though in the copy constructor. The whole idea of a const in C++ is to prevent changes, which is sadly absent in C# parameters.

Comment: @Phil, I get your point but if you change that to an struct any change in the constructor will be lost (lets say) because an struct is a value type

Comment: This is a very simple class example. What if it was a bitmap class where you have to reallocate memory? The larger the class is and memory manipulation, the more this begins to make sense.

Answer (score 4):

First off, the `const` keyword does not work the same way in C++ and C#. In C#, there is no direct equivalent of the behavior you expect. In fact, we cannot stop any method from modifying the object passed in as an argument, unless the object is immutable with respect to that method.

Let's assume that the `Vector2D` is a `class` (reference type) as opposed to a `struct` (value type). In such cases, unless you make the class immutable, there is no way to way to prevent them from being modified.

A very simple implementation of such class would be

```
class Vector2D {
    readonly int x_, y_;

    public int X { get { return x_; } }
    public int Y { get { return y_; } }

    public Vector2D(int x, int y) {
        x_ = x;
        y_ = y;
    }

    public Vector2D Clone(Vector2D vector) {
        return new Vector2D(vector.X, vector.Y);
    }
}
```

Usually in such classes, you would end up overriding the `Equals`, `GetHashcode` and the comparison `operators` `==` and `!=`

Comment: I'm referring to copy constructors in the question.

Comment: The public accessors work in this case, i.e. the private set, but it wouldn't be preferred for other cases for accessing outside of the copy constructor. I'll just assume that's how C# is and this is dangerous to larger methods without these constraint options available.

Comment: You can just do `: this(vextor.X, vector.Y)` as this better communicates your intentions, imo.

Comment: @Phil Once you make the `class` immutable, then you cannot modify it from outside the class, but you still can modify it from within. In C++ a copy constructor plays a role during initialization by compiler, which it does not play in C#. Usually a method called `Clone` (Deep or Shallow) is employed as shown in my modified example. We cannot prevent the modification of the object referred by the method argument in C#

Comment: After this new code edit: The clone works here, but imagine cloning an image. What if you accidently type 'image.m_data = null' in the copy constructor and then try reading the allocated memory. This lack of constraint causes a runtime exception. If there is a constraint in the parameters, this is prevented. But whatever, I don't design languages, but I feel C++ is smarter with using const.

Comment: @Phil please see the modified code. Now the `Vector2D` class is immutable outside of its own constructor.

Comment: That is interesting, though say you have really any method that operates on those variables, the debugger will say "error CS0191: A readonly field cannot be assigned to". For a simple example, SetX() won't work. The ideal approach is this only occurs in the copy constructor in this example.

Comment: Anyway, thanks for the help. I don't see a simple solution to this other than overlooking code to ensure the parameter argument isn't being assigned in certain cases.

Answer (score 1):

you can not use const for method parameter in C#. const can be used for local variables and fields. 
but if you want limit change value you should limit setter in properties.you can create interface and limit setter and implement interface in your class .

Look at this Code:

```
public interface ISampleInterface
{
    string Value1 { get; }
    string Value2 { get; }
}
public class Sample : ISampleInterface
{
    private string _Value1;
    public string Value1
    {
        get { return _Value1; }
        set { _Value1 = value; }
    }

    private string _Value2;
    public string Value2
    {
        get { return _Value2; }
        set { _Value2 = value; }
    }

    public Sample()
    {

    }
    public Sample(ISampleInterface sample)
    {
        //sample.Value1 = 14; not possible
        this.Value1 = sample.Value1;
        this.Value2 = sample.Value2;

    }
}
```